# Chi square and p value in GAM results in R

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, p-value, interpretation, generalized-additive-model

I would like to know how to interpret chi square and p values in GAM. 
As I understand p values basically tell us a story about the graphs - how low is the probability that there's just a straight line in the graph, eg. s()=0. Am I correct?

But what about the chi square? For example, if I have variables with Chi square values like these a (chi square = 5,4), b (12,8), c (3,1) and d (18,4) then is it correct to say that variables b and d explained most variation in dependent variable? 
Or do I have to look the p values to conclude the variables which explained most variation in dependent variable?

I'm using the mgvc package.

Thank you for the information!

Edit:

```
Parametric coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.7599     5.4602   0.139    0.889

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                       edf  Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(forest)            1.998  2.000  29.401  4.17e-07 ***
s(movement)          1.916  1.992  13.597  0.00141 ** 
s(habitatA)          1.898  1.989  23.838  5.38e-06 ***
s(habitatB)          1.873  1.984   4.944  0.06704 .  
s(year)              9.872 10.000  35.561  8.43e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.232   Deviance explained = 20.1%
UBRE = 0.16516  Scale est. = 1         n = 587
```

So is it correct to say that variable which had the highest chi squares (forest, habitatA) explained most variation in dependet variable? And what about p values. I found that sometimes a variable A had higher value of chi square but it's p value was >0,05 versus a variable B which had lower chi square but it's p value was <0,05. I thought that when chi square gets higher then the p value get's lower (or better). But it seems that that isn't the case and these two don't show similar things.

So I don't yet know for what should I look (p values or chi squares) if I want to conclude which variables were the most important and which graphs are trustworthy to say something about the relationship between two parameters.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what statistics you are quoting; are these in outputs from `gam()` models? If so, could you include that output in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't copy it, but it is the usual gam results output. It gives you the variables which you used and edf, chi square and p values for each variable.

Comment: Why can't you copy it?

Comment: Also, I don't recognise any output from `mgcv::gam` in `summary()` where you;d have chi-square stats listed as two numbers. You need to show what code you used to get those values as otherwise I'm flailing about in the dark trying to guess.

Comment: I now gave you the real results (see edit), before I did an example and I think you misread that because I wasn't clear enough. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @MP when you write 5,4 do you mean the number 5.4? If so. Oh! (and damned those foreign conventions ;-)

Comment: Yes, sorry!! I didn't think about it at all :D I meant 5.4 yes not 5 and 4.